Integral of product of periodic functions of mean value zero with algebraically independent periods is bounded
Let $f , g : \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be periodic $C^\infty$ functions with periods $p_1, p_2$, respectively. Suppose that $p_1, p_2$ are algebraically independent and that
$$
\int_0^{p_1} f(x)dx=\int_0^{p_2}g(x)dx=0.
$$
Does it follow that
$$
\int_0^N f(x)g(x)dx=O(1)
$$
as $N\to\infty$? If not, are there general conditions that will ensure that this integral is bounded?
This question is not inspired by a particular reference. I do not know the answers to the questions above. I think this type of questions are familiar to harmonic analysts, but my knowledge in this area is minimal. My intuition is that since there is no "obvious relation" between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, $f(x)g(x)$ should be "well distributed" around zero in some (heuristic) sense, and thus the integral should exhibit nontrivial cancellation.

We give a sketch of a construction for which the result doesn't hold but I have no idea what general conditions one can impose for the result to hold.
Note first that $fg$ is a quasi-periodic function with a Fourier expansion with (small $O_l((km)^{-l}$) for every $l$) coefficients at amplitudes $2\pi (k/p_1+m/p_2)$ and the condition given just means that the coefficients at amplitudes $2\pi k/p_1$ or $2\pi m/p_2$ are zero and in particular $\int_0^N f(x)g(x)dx=o(N)$ reflecting that the coefficient for amplitude $0$ is zero.
Now take $p_1=1$ and $p_2$ a number $1/\omega>0$ for which $\omega$ is a Liouville number st there is an integral sequence $q_m$ st $|\omega-p_m/q_m| \le 1/q_m^{q_m}$ and take $$f(x)=\sum_{p \ge 1}e^{-(\log p)^{3/2}}\cos 2\pi px$$ $$g(x)=\sum_{q \ge 1}e^{-(\log q)^{3/2}}\cos 2\pi \omega qx$$
Since as $p \to \infty$ we have $e^{-(\log p)^{3/2}} <<_{r} p^{-r}$ for every fixed $r>0$, we have that $f,g$ are infinitely differentiable and satisfy all the rest of the conditions, while $$2fg=\sum_{p, q \ge 1}e^{-(\log p)^{3/2}}e^{-(\log q)^{3/2}}(\cos 2\pi (p+q\omega)x+\cos 2\pi (p-q\omega)x)$$ so the amplitudes of $fg$ as a quasi-periodic functions are $2\pi (\pm p \pm q\omega), p, q \ge 1$
In particular if we choose a pair $p_m, q_m$ as above where $|\omega-p_m/q_m| \le 1/q_m^{q_m}$ so $|2\pi (q_m \omega -p_m)| \le 2\pi q_m^{-q_m+1}$ we have that the integral of that piece of $fg$ on the interval $[0, 1/|2\pi (q_m \omega -p_m)|]$ is at least $q_m^{q_m-1}e^{-(\log p_m)^{3/2}}e^{-(\log q_m)^{3/2}}\times \frac{\sin 1}{4\pi}$ and since $p_m/q_m \le 2\omega$ say, this number is huge (though of course if we let $A_m=1/|2\pi (q_m \omega -p_m)|$ the number is $o(A_m)$ as noted above) while all the rest of the integrals sum to a finite number as is not hard to see since for most $p,q$ one has $|\omega-p/q| \ge 1/(2q^2)$ with $|\omega-p/q| < 1/(2q^2)$ implying $p/q$ is a convergent of the continued fraction of $\omega$ and those are very sparse etc.
